# How to change default tab when opening System Settings on macOS Ventura?

Tags: system-settings, ventura

Whenever I open System Settings it always brings me to the ‘Appearance’ tab. However, I have a feeling that is not right and it should instead bring me to ‘General’. How do I change this?

Comment: This is clearly a crappy design choice. There is no way to change the default tab, and every single macOS Ventura machine opens System Settings to "Appearance" tab. I suggest submitting a bug report to apple.com/feedback. I already did so myself.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that ATM.

But you can use a shell script or export an application using the "script Editor.app" and put it in the dock.

shell:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
open "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.systempreferences.GeneralSettings"
```

applescript:

```
open location "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.systempreferences.GeneralSettings"
```